# RegisterHotkey blocks all other hotkeys in the system

Tags: c#, winapi, hotkeys

I created hotkeys in my application using `RegisterHotkey` function, like this

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, int fsModifiers, int vlc);
...
RegisterHotKey(FormHandle, HOTSAVE, MOD_CONTROL, (int)'S');
```

Here `FormHandle` is the handle of the main form of the app, `HOTSAVE` - is a constant - an identifier for a hotkey. 
The problem is, my application receives hotkey messages even when it is not in focus, thus preventing other applications from handling their hotkeys (e.g. `Ctrl+S` in Notepad won't work).

Could anyone please point out where the problem is? Thanks.

Comment: That's by design. A *global* hotkey also captures the key combination when your window is not active.

Comment: The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309.aspx) is quite clear on the point: "Defines a system-wide hot key."

Comment: I should say I misunderstood the docs, thanks everybody for help. I will now store a list of my hotkeys (it can be modified at runtime), unregister all of them when the window becomes unactive and register them back when it becomes active.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are confusing hotkeys with keyboard accelerators.
Hotkeys are always global, that's why you have to register them.

Keyboard accelerators however are process/window/dialog specific and usually stored in the application resources.

More about keyboard accelerators [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646335.aspx)

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not. If I, say,  have `Ctrl+S` somewhere in the main menu, I want it to be recognized even when the menu is closed.

Comment: Yes, that's normal behaviour. If the menu control doesn't handle it for you, add a `KeyPress` event handler to the form.

Comment: I'm talking about keyboard accelerators, not menu accelerators.

Comment: Menu accelerators are accessible even when the menu is not open, in fact that's their primary benefit: not requiring the menu to be open to invoke menu items. So, Menu Accelerators are exactly what you're looking for.